# tabulate frequency counts including zeros

Tags: excel

To illustrate the problem, consider the following data: `1,2,3,5,3,2`.  Enter this in a spreadsheet column and make a pivot table displaying the counts.  Making use of the information in this pivot table, I want to create a new table, with counts for every value between 1 and 5.

```
1,1
2,2
3,2
4,0
5,1
```

What is a good way to do this?  My first thought was to use `VLOOKUP`, trapping any lookup error.  But `GETPIVOTDATA` is apparently preferred for pivot tables.  In any case, I failed with both approaches.

To be a bit more specific, assume my pivot table of counts is "PivotTable1" and that I have already created a one column table holding all the needed lookup keys (i.e., the numbers from 1 to 5).  What formula should I put in the second column of this new table?

Comment: Don't you already have counts of every value between 1 and 5 in your pivot table?

Comment: you can group by range https://exceljet.net/blog/how-to-group-a-pivot-table-by-age-range

Comment: @Slai You would think this should work, but try it: even if you specify an increment of 1, the 0 value for 4 is not categorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So starting with this:

> To illustrate the problem, consider the following data: `1,2,3,5,3,2`. Enter this in a spreadsheet column and make a pivot table displaying the counts.

I then created the table like this:

```
X | Freq                                         
- | ---------------------------------------------
1 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",R3C1,"X",RC[-1]),0)
2 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",R3C1,"X",RC[-1]),0)
3 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",R3C1,"X",RC[-1]),0)
4 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",R3C1,"X",RC[-1]),0)
5 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",R3C1,"X",RC[-1]),0)
```

Or, in A1 mode:

```
X | Freq                                     
- | -----------------------------------------
1 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",F3),0)
2 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",F4),0)
3 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",F5),0)
4 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",F6),0)
5 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",F7),0)
```

The column `X` in my summary table is in column `F`.

Or as a table formula:

```
X | Freq                                       
- | -------------------------------------------
1 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",[@X]),0)
2 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",[@X]),0)
3 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",[@X]),0)
4 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",[@X]),0)
5 | =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",[@X]),0)
```

That gave me this result:

```
X | Freq
- | ----
1 | 1   
2 | 2   
3 | 2   
4 | 0   
5 | 1
```

Comment: Focusing on the table-formula answer, it appears I have a very basic question about `GETPIVOTDATA`.  I take it that both occurrences of "X" in your answer represent the name of the original table column (i.e., field), containing the underlying data.  I expected to refer entirely to the pivot table itself (using e.g. the column names and then matching to a particular value in one of the pivot table columns in order to extract that row from a different column).  Is this not possible/desirable?  Thanks!

Comment: @Alan - In the table formula the first and second `"X"` refer to the original pivot table fields, and the `[@X]` refers to the output table's column `X`. I've used the same name for the fields in both cases because they represented the same value, but you certainly don't need to do that. You can certainly hard-code the value into the formula by putting `=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("X",$A$3,"X",1),0)`. You would then need to manually change the formula for `2`, `3`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I  understand that.  My point is a bit different.  I would be inclined to replace your first occurrence of "X" with "Count of X", since that refers directly to the pivot table.  This works.  But there does not seem to be an equivalent replacement for the second occurrence of "X" (as a field specificiation).  Anyway, thanks for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not a major concern, you can bypass the pivot table and use the `COUNTIF()` function.

Create a list of all consecutive numbers that you want the counts for and use `COUNTIF()` for each of them with the first parameter being the range of your input numbers and the second being the number of the ordered result list:

```
    A    B    C    D
1   1         1    =COUNTIF(A:A,C1)
2   2         2    =COUNTIF(A:A,C2)
3   3         3    =COUNTIF(A:A,C3)
4   5         4    =COUNTIF(A:A,C4)
5   3         5    =COUNTIF(A:A,C5)
6   2
```