# grouping bug? Incorrect range

Tags: excel

To illustrate the problem, consider the following data: `1,2,3,5,3,2`. Enter this in a spreadsheet column, and then make a pivot table displaying the counts. I want to include a count of zero for the missing 4.  As a start, let us at least display the 4 as having not associated data.

In the pivot table, select one of the row labels.  Right click on it, accept the grouping from 1 to 5 by 1, and click `OK`.  Note that the final category has the inconsistent width (4-5) instead of (5-5).  Is this interval display behavior documented, or is it a bug?

Changing the stop value from 5 to 6 sill gives a wrong final category (5-6).  Changing it to 7 finally gives the right result.  But ... let's then take a closer look at that.  Go to `Field Setting | Layout and Print` and check `Show Items with No Data`.  We see that the final category is still inconsistent.

This looks like a bug to me?

Finally, can I get the pivot tables to display a correct count of 0 instead of simply displaying no data?

**Edit:** (Adding picture)

[image]

Comment: How about a picture or two?

Comment: @DougGlancy I've added a picture.  Note that the final determinate category is 6-7, in conflict with all the others.  That unwanted category width appears independent of the chosen end value for the grouping.

Comment: Interesting isn't it. You could argue that 4-5 is the only one that is correct in the original table. Try changing one of your numbers to a decimal e.g. 2.5 and see what happens.

Comment: @TomSharpe I get your point: Excel does not recognize that I have integer data, therefore it is using ordinary float binning: `(l,r]`.  But doesn't this still seem wrong?  In this case, the two 2s should end up in the bin `(1,2]` and the two 3s should end up in the bin `(2,3]`.  If so, where did that first explicit bin come from? (Start value of 1, but bin of `(0,1)`??  Excel uses still weak inequality at the lower endpoint, right?  (I've been away from it for a while.)  (I do see the strict inequality in the display.)  What are the actual value-inclusion rules at the boundaries nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

You can do better with a short *frequency table*

In **B1** enter:

```
=MIN(A:A)
```

in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(B1="","",IF(B1+1>MAX(A:A),"",B1+1))
```

and copy down.  Then in **C1** enter:

```
=IF(B1="","",COUNTIF(A:A,B1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If you are really stuck on PivotTables, see

[Mr. Excel Post](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/632498-getting-pivottable-show-zero-instead-blank-cell.html)

Comment: I discovered this possible bug while exploring best ways to create a frequency table:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286587/tabulate-frequency-counts-including-zeros/42286803 
I am interested in i. determining if it is a bug, and ii. learning if pivot tables can display the zero counts.

Comment: @Alan  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: OK!  The Mr. Excel post answers my question about displaying zeros.  I'll upvote for that.  I'm still awaiting an answer on whether I've found a bug.

Answer (score 0):

When you group them, try putting in 0.5 as the min, 5.5 as the max and 1 as the increment. Any good?

[image]

To try to address the question directly 'Is it a bug' - the definition of a [software] bug is according to Wikipedia [see ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug) 'an error, flaw, failure or fault in a computer program or system that causes it to produce an incorrect or *unexpected* result, or to behave in unintended ways'. I would add that if the software fails to perform as documented, this also would be classed as a bug. The pivot table does behave in this case in an unexpected way. But unfortunately I can find nothing in the documentation that tells me that pivot should behave differently when dealing with integer data [see ref](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-PivotTable-report-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725). Although we are not privy to the underlying code because Microsoft as far as I'm aware do not yet have an open software policy, it is a fair bet that there are two branches to this part of their code, one of which deals with integer data and one which deals with continuous data, and somehow the wrong bit of code is being called up in this particular situation.

Comment: This will give correct ranges and counts, but a bad display.  But note that I am not looking for a workaround.  I am trying to determine if I have found a bug.  (Well, I would also like to know how to display zero counts.)

Comment: It does look like a bug to me.

Comment: BTW I happen to be using Excel 2010 and can reproduce the behaviour exactly - it may depend on the version.